# A issue about elements of instantiation of pack expansion

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider the following rule:

> The instantiation of a pack expansion that is neither a sizeof... expression nor a fold-expression produces a list E<sub>1</sub>,E<sub>2</sub>,...E<sub>N</sub> , where N is the number of elements in the pack expansion parameters. Each E<sub>i</sub> is generated by instantiating the pattern and replacing each pack expansion parameter with its ith element. Such an element, in the context of the instantiation, is interpreted as follows:
>
> > - if the pack is a template parameter pack, the element is a **template parameter** of the corresponding kind (type or non-type) designating the type or value from the template argument; otherwise,
> > - if the pack is a function parameter pack, the element is an id-expression designating the function parameter that resulted from the instantiation of the pattern where the pack is declared.

Please note the bold wording. This rule only says the case that the pack expansion occurs in `template-parameter-list`, such as:

```cpp
template<typename...T>
struct Enclose{
  template<T...t>  // pack expansion
  struct content{
  };
}; 
int main(){
    Enclose<int,char>::content<1,'0'> d;
}
```

Only the pack expansion occurs in this context will its element be called a `template parameter`. However as a general rule, the pack expansion can not only occur in the `template-parameter-list` but also it can occur in `template-argument-list` and anything others that permitted(which is listed in [temp.variadic#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#4)). In these contexts, the instantiated entities are not `template parameter`. So, as a general rule to describe what these elements are when instantiate the pattern of a pack expansion which contains the **template parameter pack**, Does this paragraph exist a defect which does not cover other cases?

Comment: @TedLyngmo  That's not the same question and the answers in that link is for bullet 2 which is omitted in my question.

Comment: _"Only the pack expansion occurs in this context will its element be called a template parameter"_, no? Template parameters are... parameters from templates. Just as you would call function parameters arguments when used as arguments, and just variables if used anywhere else.

Comment: @PasserBy  For `std::tuple<T...>`, Could the instantiated element be called a template parameter? we can only say the element is template-argument.

Comment: They are template parameters used as template arguments. So yes.

Comment: @PasserBy So , how about `std::tuple<std::tuple<T>...>`, the pattern is `std::tuple<T>`, anyhow, we can't say such an entity `std::tuple<T>` is the template parameter,Right?

Comment: It's not, the "element" is the expanded `T`, which is a template parameter. `std::tuple<T>` is the "pattern".

Comment: @PasserBy  why do you think the "element" is the expanded `T` instead of `Ei`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220867/discussion-between-passer-by-and-jack-x).

Comment: Your code snippet is invalid and makes no sense. "This rule only says the case that the pack expansion occurs in template-parameter-list" Where does it say that? You never quote any part of the standard that mentions template-parameter-list.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  My example is valid, that's a case of pack expansion. My point is that does the wording "template parameter" refer to template parameter declaration or to use of template parameter? Unlike what says in the second bullet(where use the id-expression, that implies use of function parameter), the way to express is not uniform. Maybe change the wording `template parameter` to `an identifier designating the template parameter` for the first bullet, that would be easy to understand it.

Comment: Yes sorry it is valid. The wording "template parameter" refers to a template parameter. If they wanted to say "declaration", they would say "declaration". The element is not an identifier. The identifier T designates a parameter pack. Each element is an individual element of the pack. There is no identifier that designates each element, only a pack as a whole.

Comment: On the other thought maybe you are right and the standard should have said "identifier" in place of "template parameter".

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  I didn't say that the "identifier" is the literal `T`. My thought is, Since the second bullet use the hypothetical "id-expression" to denote the use of corresponding function parameter, why would the first bullet not use the uniform way such as using an  invented `identifier` to denote the use of `ith` template parameter? after all, the identifier(opt) can be used to denote any kind of template parameter(as defined in [temp.param#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#1)). That will more easy to read the first bullet.